# problem during compilation

Tags: chown

I am learning how to compile using your [CompilingEasyHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) guide. But as soon as I run the command shown below in the terminal, it shows the following error:

```
tejas@tejas-AU909AA-ACJ-CQ3120IX:~$ sudo chown $tejas /usr/local/src
chown: missing operand after ‘/usr/local/src’
```

Any idea how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to replace `$USER` by your own session login name (tejas) as this variable already contains "tejas".

So the right command to use is:

```
sudo chown $USER /usr/local/src
```

The variables `$ENV`, `$LOGNAME`, `$MAIL`, `$TERM`, `$USER`, and `$USERNAME` are not Bash builtins. These are, however, often set as environmental variables in one of the Bash or login startup files.

Source: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Answer (score 2):

While [you don't have to](https://askubuntu.com/a/521896/22949) manually substitute your username for `$USER`, you can if you like. You just have to put it *in place of* the whole "word" `$USER`, not just `USER`. That is, leave off the `$` in what you write:

```
sudo chown tejas /usr/local/src
```

This is because `$` before a "name" signifies it is the name of a variable and that the variable should be dereferenced--that is, replaced by the value stored in it. `USER` is an environment variable that holds your username.

In contrast, `tejas` is (probably) not defined (in the sense of being a variable that has been assigned some value). In a shell, a variable that is not defined is treated, in most ways, like it is empty--i.e., holding the empty (i.e., zero-length) string of text. So `$tejas` is replaced by *nothing* and the command that actually gets run is `sudo chown /usr/local/src`, which cannot work.