# Changing ownership of folder not working!

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory, environment-variables, chown

I am trying to change the ownership of a folder and subfolders by typing either of these:

```
sudo chown $user -R /usr/bin/.folder/
sudo chown $user -R /usr/bin/folder/
sudo chown $user -R /usr/bin/.folder
sudo chown $user -R /usr/bin/folder
```

But I get the output:

```
chown: missing operand after '/usr/bin/.folder/'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

#### Why Lower-Case `$user` Doesn't Work

To clarify and expand upon what others [have](https://askubuntu.com/a/533219/22949) [said](https://askubuntu.com/a/533218/22949), shell and environment variables are case-sensitive. `user` and `USER` are different variables, so their contents (which `$user` and `$USER` expand to, respectively) may be different. Typically, no variable called `user` is defined and `$user` is expanded to nothing, while what you want is `$USER` which would expand to your username.

The `echo` command is usually suitable for checking the value of a variable:

```
$ echo "$user"

$ echo "$USER"
ek
```

<sup>For variables whose values don't contain any blank spaces, the quotes may be removed without affecting the output.

So I could've just used `echo $USER` if I wanted.</sup>

#### Another Option, for `chown`

You probably know your own username, so you can just use it in place of `$USER`. If you do this, [make sure to omit the `$` sign](https://askubuntu.com/a/521911/22949).

For example, since my username is `ek`, I could use:

```
sudo chown ek -R /usr/bin/.folder/
```

#### Why You Get *That* Error

You might be wondering why you get the particular error message:

```
chown: missing operand after '/usr/bin/.folder/'
```

That message actually is informative, in that when you see a message like that from a command where you expanded variables, it suggests one or more of your expanded variables may have been unintentionally empty or unset.

You ran `sudo chown $user -R /usr/bin/.folder/`, and since `user` was probably undefined, `$user` expanded to nothing and it was equivalent to running:

```
sudo chown -R /usr/bin/.folder/
```

The `-R` option makes `chown` act on every file in a directory tree, as you probably know. Since `$user` expanded to nothing, `/usr/bin/.folder/` was the first *non-option* argument to `chown`, and thus was interpreted as the argument specifying the desired ownership (such as a username). `/usr/bin/.folder` is not valid syntax for that, but that particular error went unreported because a different error stopped `chown` first: there were no more arguments, and so there was nothing specified for `chown` to operate *on*.

To put it another way, if I ran `sudo chown $USER -R /usr/bin/.folder/`, it would expand to `sudo chown ek -R /usr/bin/.folder/` and `chown` would interpret its arguments this way:

- `ek`: username, since no username argument has been passed yet
- `-R`: recursive option (the leading `-` is what makes `chown` know it's an option argument)
- `/usr/bin/.folder/`: file or directory to change ownership on, since the username was already passed

But if I ran `sudo chown $user -R /usr/bin/.folder`, it would expand to `sudo chown -R /usr/bin/.folder/` and `chown` would interpret its arguments this way:

- `-R`: recursive option
- `/usr/bin/.folder/`: username, since no username argument has been passed yet

#### *Further Reading*

For more information, you may be interested in:

- [BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments)
- [BashGuide/Parameters](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters)
- [`man chown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/chown.1.html)

Answer (score 6):

Please use `$USER` instead of `$user`.

```
sudo chown $USER -R /usr/bin/.folder/
```

Answer (score 2):

The `user` variable is probably empty. Try `$USER`.